# Hibernate - avoid string in property name when making predicate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have following entity:

```
@Entity
MyClass{

    @Column(length = 6, nullable = true)
    @Type(type = "mypackage.MyInnerClassHibernateType")
    @Mergable
    private MyInnerClass myProperty;

    ...

}
```

And when I need to make a predicate on `myProperty` I make it like this:

```
criteriaBuilder.equal(queryRoot.get("myProperty"), value);
```

This works fine, but I do not like using "myProperty" string in query. In case I rename property I have to go through all such strings and rename it there. I find this design error-prone.

Is there any option how to avoid using hard-coded string?

Comment: The thing you need is Type-safe Metamodels. Described here https://developer.ibm.com/languages/java/articles/j-typesafejpa/

Comment: yes, something like this. But how to incorporate it to my solution? I have tried to enter `queryRoot.get(MyClass_.myProperty)` but this obviously does not compile. What am I missing here?

Comment: You need to include annotation processor to your dependencies: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpamodelgen/1.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#chapter-usage. Processor will automatically create metamodels for your classes marked with `@Entity` annotation during build. In your case it will generate `MyClass_` for `MyClass` class

Comment: thanks so much, I am going to give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finished with using Lombok's [@FieldNameConstants](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/FieldNameConstants).

If you annotate your class like this:

```
@FieldNameConstants
public class FieldNameConstantsExample {
  private final String iAmAField;
  private final int andSoAmI;
  @FieldNameConstants.Exclude private final int asAmI;
}
```

you can then access field names in a following way:

```
FieldNameConstantsExample.Fields.iAmAField;
```

which returns you string containing the name of a property.